# Flutter - GetX: The list literal type 'List<Item>' isn't of expected type 'RxList<Item>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm a beginner of Flutter. I'm making a sort of shopping list app.
Using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnevdXDH25Q I'm trying to use GetX for state management.

I have this class named 'Items' which has some attributes. I create a list of Items which I'll later show as cards.

I can't wrap my head around this.

This is the code of the class on which I'm working right now.

```
class ItemsController extends GetxController {
  RxList<Item> items = [].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    loadItems();
  }

  loadItems() {
    items = [
      Item(
        name: 'olio',
        description: '',
        quantity: 1,
      ),
      Item(
        name: 'mozzarella',
        description: 'di bufala',
        quantity: 4,
      ),
    ];

    items.assignAll(items);
  }
}
```

I tried almost everything I could, but everytime Android Studio gives this error:
**The list literal type 'List' isn't of expected type 'RxList'.**

I also tried to append `.cast<Item>();` to 'items' list but I have the message

```
type 'RxList<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'RxList<Item>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You have assigned a List to RxList so change that to

```
  RxList<Item> items = <Item>[].obs;
```

or just

```
  var items = [].obs;
```

- In the loadItems function you have assigned a List to RxList so change that as follows

```
  loadItems() {
    List<Item> newItems = [
      Item(
        name: 'olio',
        description: '',
        quantity: 1,
      ),
      Item(
        name: 'mozzarella',
        description: 'di bufala',
        quantity: 4,
      ),
    ];
    items.assignAll(newItems);
  }
```

or simply

```
  loadItems() {
    items.assignAll([
      Item(
        name: 'olio',
        description: '',
        quantity: 1,
      ),
      Item(
        name: 'mozzarella',
        description: 'di bufala',
        quantity: 4,
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

it's a bit confusing at the start but you will get the get little by little

Answer (score 1):

You Forget to Import

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
```

So Just Add this Line .obs Will Work